# how to factor these two angular elements into a single conditional angular template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm currently displaying image layers or text layers using the following angular template

```html
<div *ngFor="let layer of getLayers()">
    <img *ngIf="(layer.type === layerType.Image)"
        id={{layer.id}}
        class="floatLayer" cdkDrag
        (cdkDragStarted)="layerDragStarted($event)"
        (cdkDragEnded)="layerDragEnded($event)"
        (click)="selectLayerByClick(layer)"
        [src]="(layer | castTo: imageLayer).img_src" 
        [style.left]="layer.getLeftPx()"
        [style.top]="layer.getTopPx()"
        [style.z-index]="layer.getZindex()"
        [style.transform]="layer.getTransform()"
        [style.outline]="(layer.selected) ? 'dashed 1px red':''"
    />
    <div *ngIf="(layer.type === layerType.Text)" 
        id={{layer.id}}
        class = "floatLayer" cdkDrag
        (cdkDragStarted)="layerDragStarted($event)"
        (cdkDragEnded)="layerDragEnded($event)"
        (click)="selectLayerByClick(layer)"
        [style.left]="layer.getLeftPx()"
        [style.top]="layer.getTopPx()"
        [style.transform]="layer.getTransform()"
        [style.z-index]="layer.getZindex()"
        [style.outline]="(layer.selected) ? 'dashed 1px red':''"
    >
        <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
            {{(layer | castTo: textLayer).text}}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the few differences between them is that one has the source of the image `[src]`
while the other contains a `<span>` with a text of the layer.

Both `ImageLayer` and `TextLayer` inherit from `BaseLayer`

Is there a way to create single element that can render both type of layers without repeating all those `[style.*]` and event wiring and how to do it.

**Things I've tried**

I have tried using `*ngIf*` to render the parts that are needed only for images or only text.

I have also google around without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution

```html
<div 
    id={{layer.id}}
    class = "floatLayer" cdkDrag
    (cdkDragStarted)="layerDragStarted($event)"
    (cdkDragEnded)="layerDragEnded($event)"
    (click)="selectLayerByClick(layer)"
    [style.left]="layer.getLeftPx()"
    [style.top]="layer.getTopPx()"
    [style.transform]="layer.getTransform()"
    [style.z-index]="layer.getZindex()"
    [style.outline]="(layer.selected) ? 'dashed 1px red':''"
    [cdkDragDisabled]="!(layer.selected)"
>
    <span *ngIf="(layer.type === layerType.Text)" style="white-space: nowrap;">
        {{(layer | castTo: textLayer).text}}
    </span>
    <img *ngIf="(layer.type === layerType.Image)" [src]="(layer | castTo: imageLayer).img_src" >
</div>
```

I could also use `[ngStyle]` to factor out all those `[style.*]`